# How to convert negative timedelta value to positive

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

[image]

I am working with a dataset that contains negative timedelta values (first picture ride_length column) it is calculated by ['ended_at'] - ['started_at'] (first picture) how do I remove the negative sign?

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's `abs` function. e.g.:

```
In [1]: from datetime import timedelta
In [2]: td = timedelta(days=-1)
In [3]: td
Out[3]: datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
In [4]: abs(td)
Out[4]: datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: If I use abs() then all the negative timedelta values become 0 days.